# Are the any benefits of using a futures long position with no leverage over a spot buy?

Tags: futures

When you want to bet that a price on a certain stock will go up, what are the benefits of going in a futures long position, over doing a spot buy? Assuming that you are not using leverage and doing on 1X orders only.

Comment: Can you name a future where you don't have leverage?

Comment: I think that all trading platforms have the possibility to do a 1X long position